# Facebook login give me already authorized this app everytime ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

My app should implement login with facebook but I have noticed that every time I want to login the facebook tell me you are already authorize this app , the question if I already authorized the app the facebook should return automatically without pressing the okey button as I saw in other applications ?

see link :http://dugars.com/images/t13_7_authorize.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Its to simple Go to Your Facebook Account.

Login--> Setting--> App Setting  --> Delete particular app

hope now this will as per your expectation...

If not then **logout** from your safari browser in your device.

Comment: hi,how to avoid that screen,when user click login button it dont ask "you are already authorize this app" cancel or ok button.direct it should open login page in my app

Comment: you should maintain its permission which is available in FB SDK. read docs carefully and try.currently its not recalling me which one permission u r missing

Answer (score 1):

If you logged in with safari, safari caches it and remebers you are logged in. If you are in simulator, try iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings

Comment: i checked some apps when i login in first time its ask cancel or ok. i click ok and then logout app and login agin its not asking "you are already authorize this app" direct open ofter page

Answer (score 1):

You should check if there is a current session before logging in with `FBSDKLoginManager`. Do not use `[loginManager logout]` before logging in.

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) 
 {
      NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);
      // Now get details using graphpath. 
 } else {
     // login with permissions using FBSDKLoginManager and get details using graphpath in completion

 }
```